# What's the geometry of $|r - r_1| + |r - r_2| = k$ where $k > |r_1 - r_2|$ in $2$ dimensions?

Tags: calculus, geometry, vectors

Exercise $12.2.40$.  If $r = \langle x,y \rangle$, $r_1 = \langle x_1, y_1\rangle$, $r_2 = \langle x_2, y_2\rangle$, describe the set of all points $(x,y)$ such that $|r - r_1| + |r + r_2| = k$ where $k > |r_1 - r_2|$.

I'm not sure how to do this.  Here's my reasoning.

I look first at $|r - r_1| + |r + r_2| = k$ where $k = |r_1 - r_2|$.  (A different problem.)

<strike>Given we're in two dimensions, the expression $|r - r_1| \leq k_1$ represents a disk of some radius centered at the tip of the vector $r_1$.  (Similarly for $|r - r_2| \leq k_2$.)  Also, the expression $|r_1 - r_2|$ represents the distance between the two disk centers.</strike>

Considering the expression $|r - r_1|$ it is just the distance from the tip of the vector $r$ to the tip of the vector $r_1$.  So if I add this distance to $|r - r_2|$, I'm just getting a larger distance.  If I want this larger distance to be equal to $k = |r_1 - r_2|$, then I think I get a circle of radius equal to the distance between the tips of $r_1$ and $r_2$.

The original problem asks for $k > |r_1 - r_2|$, which can be represented by any point outside the circle $|r - r_1| + |r - r_2| = |r_1 - r_2|$, hence giving me the complement of a disk of radius |r_1 - r_2|.  (But I don't know where this disk is centered nor am I sure whether $|r - r_1| + |r - r_2|$ is a circle.)

So I don't know how to do this.

Reference: 
Calculus, James Stewart, 5th edition, exercise 12.2.40.

**UPDATE $1$**:  After @OsamaGhani's hint, I managed to understand.  The equation is the ellipse's equation in vector notation.  So the equation represents the complement of an ellipsis with foci at the tip of $r_1$ and $r_2$.  I've striked out my flawed original reasoning.

Comment: This is the locus of points whose sum of distances to two points is constant. Hint: do you know any conic sections defined by the property?

Comment: You're making me think of an ellipse.

Comment: That’s exactly right!

Comment: I think I got it.  Thanks very much.  That appears to be the complement of an ellipse --- in vector notation.

Answer (score 1):

That    $$ |r - r_1| + |r + r_2| = k$$  is the equation of an ellipse with foci  located at $r_1$ and  $-r_2$

Comment: Thank you.  It's clear to me now.  Also, I'm sorry for not spotting the typo in the title (now fixed).  The expression was meant to be $|r - r_1| + |r + r_2|$, but that's only a change in sign which made no difference.

Comment: Impressive.  I made the same typo yet again.  It was meant to be $|r - r_1| + |r - r_2|$.